# Why would the Möbius transform of a segment on a circle be perpendicular to the real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Dear potential answerer,

I am slightly confused with the following problem:

> Given the möbius transformation $w=\frac{z-a}{z-b}$ with $a,b \in \mathscr{C}$ determine the image of the circle that has the segment $[a,b]$ as its diameter.

Clearly, I have a circle with diameter $\left|a-b\right|$ centered on $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Now, It seems good to note that $(a,b)$ is mapped to $(0, \infty)$. A third point would then determine the image. It has to lie on the circle?

The solution should be:

> The circle is mapped to a straight line, because b is mapped to $\infty$; this line passes through 0 and is perpendicular to the real axis.

Why would it be perpendicular to the real axis? The information I have is, so far, that $(a,b)$ maps to $(0, \infty)$; I do not know a third point that maps to i.

So, how would you solve this? Is there some sort of lemma that I forgot? Or is there a valid way to choose a third point quickly?

Thanks in advance,
Daimonie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Möbius transformations preserve angles. The circle is perpendicular to the diameter. The diameter is transformed into $(-\infty,0]$. The image of the circle is then perpendicular to the real axis.

Answer (score 1):

$z \mapsto \frac{z - a}{z-b}$ maps the center of the circle $\frac{a+b}{2}$ to $-1$. Since $a$ is mapped to $0$ and $b$ to $\infty$, the diameter $[a, b]$ of the circle is mapped to $\mathbb{R}$.
Now you have to know that Möbius transforms are conformal, i.e. they locally preserve angles. The diameter $[a, b]$ intersects the circle under an angle of $90^\circ$. Therefore the image of the circle and the diameter must intersect under an angle of $90^\circ$.

Comment: A property it is! Thanks :)